# How to reduce the package size

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have implemented an Android application using Xamarin:

The size of the .apk is **13.6MB** with:

- **Configuration**: Release
- **Linking**: Sdk Assemblies Only
- **Suported architectures**: armeabi,armeabi-v7a

Here is the overview of sizes of the main components taken from the compiled .apk:

(these are the **uncompressed** sizes, I unarchived the .apk to a directory and looked to the files in **Windows Explorer**):

- **classes.dex** (1.23 KB)
- **the two libmonodroid.iso (armeabi + armeabi-v7a)** (5.58 MB)
- **all Mono.xxx.dll** (3.89 MB)
- **mscorlib.dll** (1.51 MB)
- **all System.xxx.dll** (2.56 MB)
- **My app assemblies** (the Droid app + one PCL)  (204 KB)
- **MvvmCross + plugins** (599 KB)
- **Xamarin ActionbarSherlock** (348 KB)
- **ZXing.monoandroid** (413 KB)
- **PCL Newtonsoft.Json** (398 KB)
- **PCL Microsoft HTTP Client libraries (System.Net.Http.dll)** (110KB)
- **'res' folder** (Size: 451KB Size on disk: 816KB) - because some files are 1KB they produce fragmentation, so *Actual size* vs *Size on disk* is significantly different
- **all PNG files** (Size: 325KB Size on Disk: 496KB on disk)

What can I do in order to reduce the size of the compiled .apk?

I find it pretty big.

Comment: Did you include any icons or splashscreens in the .apk?

Comment: Some of these libraries are redundant to Android's libraries like Newtonsoft.Json and System.Net.Http.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn good point but I am using the PCL version of the libraries, they are refernced by my PCL assembly; I updated my list.

Comment: I'd say do a sanity check and do a 'du -m' on your apps root directory. Flush out any big files that you may not be thinking of.  With just small amounts of code apps should really be in the 1-3 MB range.

Comment: @ErikKerber that's a unix command. this is a Xamarin Android app. I am  looking to the unarchived .apk.

Comment: Sigh... it's a command that works on OS X or any POSIX system. If you're stuck in Windows-World, then there's WinDirStat.  The point is there is you are either *not* doing any linking, or there is something that you are packaging up that you are not disclosing above.

Comment: @ErikKerber there isn't anything I am not aware of in terms of resource files or anything like that

Comment: 13MB is a mean size of a normal Xamarin.Android app. I never managed to get lower than 8MB on Android. On iOS i managed to get 4 MB.

Comment: @Softlion thanks for sharing your experience, it's helpful

Comment: @AndreiN. Have you reduce your apk size ? If yes, please tell me how can I also ?

Comment: 13mb is good. Mine is around 20mb and it includes almost no images and just v4 and v7 libraries + Newtonsoft.Json and Picasso.

Answer (score 2):

Use linking: Sdk + User Assemblies, and go through the difficult process of marking classes with the Preserve attribute (see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/). You can check which class is missing when your app crashes in the android log. It should be only the classes used dynamically by reflection or using an IoC.

You can also create 2 separate packages, one with armeabi only (for very old devices), one with armeabiv7a, and one with x86 (currently your app will just crash on x86 android devices). Google play supports having 3 separate packages with different capabilities (don"t forget to change the capabilities in your manifest file for each package)

Comment: awesome answer. I was aware already of these options. 2nd option looks easy and really viable. 1st one however I don't think it's so easy. Imagine a very specific class which get used ONLY in a specific moment and scenario in the app. Requires testing thoroughly and repeat it for each new feature or modification done in the app. I will wait a bit more before marking your comment as answer. thanks again

Comment: I wonder why when using Sdk + User Assemblies the Linker is not able to know by itself the classes being used. If it's too much

Comment: It knows classes being used, but not classes that are loaded dynamically, or instantiated through reflection. And it does not know methods called through reflection. There should not be much in your app. But sure, it is a hard process.

Comment: yes, code which is dynamically loaded might be a bit out of scope for a linker, but maybe Xamarin or someone else writes a tool? I guess this means being able to parse the IL to catch dynamic loading. I probably won't do too much dynamic loading myself but the libraries I am using might be.

Comment: If you use mvvmcross or an IoC then yes you use dynamic loading. Complete static analysis of dynamic programs work only in a functional language like F# or any lambda based program. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus for further informations.